# HTML: Dynamic size of elements

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I'm looking for a way to change the size of elements dynamically to the size of a page.
**I know that is possible with javascript. :-)** 
But there is also a new solution with the CSS units: **vw**, **vh**, **vmin** and **vmax**. These units are relative to the viewport and it works really good. I have only one problem. My page should have a minimum size. So i also have to set a minimum size for the viewport to give the dependent elements a minimum size. Unfortunately, i found no solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

### **I think your best bet is using CSS media queries.**

Depending on your needs you can either define a completely different style sheet for your page based on the present media state (usually device-width) or specific elements.

E.g.

**Different style sheets**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='css/small.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)' href='css/large.css' />
```

Where the styles defined in `small.css` is applied only when the viewport is 700px or less and those of `large.css` are applied when it's 701px upwards.

---

**Size specific rules:**

```
body {
    background: #000;
    color: red;
}


//styles within this block are only applied when the window is <= 700px
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #258;
  }
}
```

There's plenty more of this on [Chris Coyer's CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) (which itself makes very heavy use of CSS media queries)

Additionally [support of viewport-units is pretty low](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) and whilst media queries aren't ubiquitous they're [certainly much more prevalent](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) (roughly twice so).

Comment: Additionally, you could just try basic % attributes such as width: 50%? Would that achieve what you're after? And I'd set a min-width attribute for your the body element regarding the minimum width issue

Comment: Yes, but then the proportion between height and width is not always the same. I could use this when i can give the width in percentage of the height. Is that possible without javascript?

Comment: Yes, using media-queries, although it would change at a given break-point so you wouldn't be able to get the smooth transition like you would with setting % values for widths.

Comment: Additionally, setting `margin` and `percent` as percent define them in terms of a percent of the width of the element rather than the height, so this might go some way to achieving the effect you are after.